# Jquery - $.GET Place In Closest Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

So this is probably very easy but for some reason I can't get it to work.  I have a $.get function that runs properly. I want the data/results to load into the closest div.  When I identify the div specifically, everything works fine:

```
$.get( lk, function(data) {
        $("div.tcontainer").html(data);
    });
```

But when I try to look for the closest div, it does not work.  I have a few divs on the page (dynamically) and they have the same attributes so i need to find the closest div and load the data into that div like:

```
$.get( lk, function(data) {
        $(this).closest("div.tcontainer").html(data);
    });
```

But this does not work.  Can someone help me find the closest div using the code above.  Thank you.

Comment: closest DIV of what??? Sounds like you just need to use a varaible as `this` reference. `this` inside `$.get()` success callback is referring to jqXHR object. FYI, you could instead use `$.ajax()` and pass as `context` option `this`: `context: this,`

Comment: what is $(this)?? provide html code please

Comment: We all have the same question :)

Answer (score 2):

The value of your `this` variable is not a DOM object in that context. You will need to set another closure variable and then access that closure variable inside the callback. If your closure value that you want is `this`, then do `var that = this;` and replace `$(this)` with `$(that)`